# JavaScript element style change with dynamic id

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to put a line through a list item when the check box next to it is checked. I have managed to do it but I can't check if the the box is checked.

**JS File**

```
    if(document.getElementById(theID).checked){

document.getElementById(theID).setAttribute("style", "text-decoration:line-through");
}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
                echo'<ol>';
            foreach($to_do_XML->task as $item)
            {
                $theID = $item['id'];

            echo '<li id="'.$theID.'">'.$item.'</li>' ;?><form ><input  onclick="return cross('<?=$theID?>');" type="checkbox" name="done<?php $li_id_num_done ?>"/></form>
                 <?php     

            }
            echo '</ol>';
```

i should also add that the list item is being added within a foreach loop looping trough xml elements

The above code does nothing any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you should try to put some effort in your indentation ;) Also, I would avoid using "setAttribute()" but use classes instead.

Comment: sorry. if i use classes i wont be able to cross off each li indivualy.

Comment: ofcourse you can, but you have to set the class on a single input element, not the container.

Comment: Why do you generate so many forms?

Comment: @ericG i need a checkbox per li forms arnt being submitted so idont believe it to be an issue

Answer (score 4):

If `$theID` is a string, you need quotes around it:

```
     <input  onclick="return cross('<?php echo $theID; ?>');" type="checkbox" name="done<?php $li_id_num_done ?>"/>
```

**Also remove this from your function:**

```
got_elements_id
```

It will cause a reference error.

Comment: Could "return cross( this.checked )" return unpredictable data? I.e. could a wrong context be troublesome?

Comment: @EricG if you do that, you won't have the ID or a reference to the element to do the strikeout.

Comment: I think you mean `onclick="return cross('<?=$theID?>');"`

Comment: no that didnt fix it. it works if i comment out the if statement

Comment: @MrCode "return cross(this)" should be better, I thought the style was applied on another object, my bad. http://jsfiddle.net/QnQ4k/

Comment: @EricG neither `return cross(this)` or `return cross(this.checked)` will do what OP wants.

Comment: @EricG if i doit the way is jsfiddle i cant use the unique id

Comment: @Lonergan6275 have you tried the updated code in the answer? It wasn't me that posted the JSFiddle, I have already said that method won't work.

Comment: @Lonergan6275 you are using short open tags, which isn't always enabled. Use the long version - see my edit. If it still doesn't work (which it should), then view your error console. Also, remove `got_elements_id` from the function!

Comment: @MrCode are u referring to <?php rather than <?

Comment: @Lonergan6275 yes see my update. Also remove `got_elements_id`

Comment: @MrCode done and done still no joy to the console. got the following err in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Comment: @Lonergan6275 right click the browser and view>source, then paste a sample of the checkbox and list item source.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better I believe:

```
echo '<li id="'.$theID.'">'.$item.'</li>' ;?>
<form >
    <input  onclick="return cross('<? echo $theID; ?>');" type="checkbox" name="done<?php $li_id_num_done ?>"/>
</form>
```

And

```
function cross( id ){

    var element = document.getElementById( id );
    if( element.checked){

        element.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
function cross( id ){

    var element = document.getElementById( id );        
    element.style.textDecoration = element.checked ? "line-through" : "";
}
```

Which also enables unchecking and removing the linethrough.

Comment: What doesnt it do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: cross of the li next to the checkbox

Comment: I finally see that it had the ID from a different element as a parameter, my bad.